# Is it possible for an absorption refrigerator to pump heat to a reservoir that is at a higher temperature than the heat source used to run it?

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation, heat-engine, thermal-conduction

Judging by the wiki page I get the feeling that this type of heat pump would not function if it's radiator were hotter than the heat source, but I can't quite put into words why and I feel like there might be something that I'm misunderstanding.

Edit: Here is the link to the wikipedia page on it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_refrigerator

Comment: A start to improving this question would be to link to the wikipedia page you're discussing.

Comment: The heat source is not used to run the refrigerator; electrical work is supplied to run it.

Comment: @ChetMiller This isn't that type of refrigerator. An absorption refrigerator runs on heat alone. You're thinking of a compression refrigerator, which uses an electrical or some other type of motor to provide torque which runs it's compression cycle.